# Combining solutions to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the given PDE:

$u_{xx}=u_{yy}$

where the solution must be in the form: $u(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$.

By solving this using the product rule, I get

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
\\
f_{xx}=f(x)C\\
g_{yy}=g(y)C\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

which I solve separately, and obtain

\begin{equation}
f(x)=e^{\sqrt{c}x}+e^{-\sqrt{c}x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g(y)=e^{\sqrt{c}y}+e^{-\sqrt{c}y}
\end{equation}

Since $u(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$ I multiple the solutions and obtain:

\begin{equation}
(e^{\sqrt{c}x}+e^{-\sqrt{c}x})(e^{\sqrt{c}y}+e^{-\sqrt{c}y}) = 4 cosh(\sqrt{c}x) cosh(\sqrt{c}y)
\end{equation}

Then they have to satisfy the I.C (which appear double-valued):

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
 ff(0)=0, \ f(1)=0, \ f(1/4)=1/2,  \\
g(1/4)=g(1/2)=1
\end{array}
\end{equation}

But since the I.C. are double-valued, which appears wrong, I change I.C. to $f(0.25)=g(0.25)=1$

So I do:
\begin{equation}
4 cosh(\sqrt{c}\cdot0.25) cosh(\sqrt{c}\cdot0.25)=1
\end{equation}

and I obtain $c=-\frac{16\pi^2}{9}$. So, the full solution appears to be:

\begin{equation}
u(x,y)=4 cosh(\frac{4i\pi}{3}x) cosh(\frac{4i\pi}{3}y)
\end{equation}

The solution is then plotted:

[image]

Does this seem reasonable?

Thanks

Comment: What are the initial conditions for $u$, exactly? That's the wave equation, which you usually solve by using $x \pm y$ as new variables, rather than with separation of variables.

Comment: I take they have to be multiplied as $u(x,y)=f(x)*g(y)$

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You give conditions for $f$ and $g$, but where did you get them from? What was the formulation of **original** problem (and in what [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) did you encounter it)? What were the conditions on the function $u$?

Comment: They come from an exercise that was hand-written by a Professor, that is, they do not come from a printed book. So to me, it appears that he has done a mistake on the double-valuedness of f(x) in the IC.